# warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. React-Native 62.2

Tags: react-native

I am using React-Native to develop Android-APP, After React-Native version upgrading from 61.0 to 0-62.2, I encountered a problem.

**Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`**

I searched for the warning in the google but i didn't find any proper solution 
every one showing below code as a solution

```
 state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
  }
componentDidMount() {
  Animated.spring(
    this.state.animation,
    {
      toValue: 250,
      duration: 2000,
      friction: 1,
      tension: 20
    }
  ).start();
}
```

but i never used above code in my app,
I am getting this error only after upgrading to "react-native": "^0.62.2",
 If anyone know the solution please help me

Answer (score 3):

If you've never used `Animated`, then I'm sure that this warning caused by some 3rd-party library that you're using.

Check libraries that provide any Modals, Notifications, Switches, Sliders, Animations, or any other animated stuff and try to upgrade them to the latest version or at least check new releases or issues on GitHub.

In case you've used `Animated`, make sure that you've passed `useNativeDriver: true/false` to all `Animated.spring`, `Animated.decay`, `Animated.timing` and `Animated.event` methods as a second parameter. More details about `useNativeDriver`: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated

I hope that you will find a solution!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestion ,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , i am getting this error do to   'react-native-video-controls'
any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

This is **only to suppress** the warning!!!

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`']);
```

@Seniv's answer above is more specific on solving the warning from the warning causing unspecific packages.

[Reference Issue on Github](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1782#issuecomment-703173579)